# How can an Azure Function 2.x get access to a stable_sid?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When I coded my Azure Function using v1, I was able to get access to the user's `sid` like this:

```
public static bool TryGetUserId(out string userId)
{
    userId = string.Empty;

    IPrincipal currentPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

    if (currentPrincipal is null)
        return false;

    userId = currentPrincipal.GetNameIdentifier();

    return false == string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId);
}
```

I then moved my Azure Function to the v2 preview and I read that [the ClaimsPrincipal were not hydrated anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#user-claims). I ended using the following algorithm:

```
public static bool TryGetUserId(HttpRequestMessage request, out string userId)
{
    userId = string.Empty;

    KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> principalId = request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(header => string.Equals(header.Key, "X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));

    if (principalId.Value.Count() != 1)
         return false;

    userId = principalId.Value.First();

    return false == string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId);
}
```

Here is a sample of my Azure Function:

```
[FunctionName("FindAccount")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestMessage request, ILogger logger)
{
    try
    {
        if (false == FunctionHelper.TryGetUserId(request, out userId))
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

        // Looks for an account matching the sid.
    }
    catch (AccountNotFoundException)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"No account has been found for user.");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

It does not work anymore as the header is not the sid anymore but either a `long` or `int` value, whether I am using a Google account or a Microsoft account.

**Setup**

I have an iOS application that directs the user to either Google or Microsoft to be authenticated and then the iOS application connects the Azure Function on the specific endpoints (`/.auth/login/microsoftaccount` or `/.auth/login/google`) to post the received tokens, as described in the Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authentication-flow).

**Question**

How can an Azure Function v2 get access to the user's `sid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below approach and follow the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33) . This has been discussed in detail with code snippets.

```html
public static async Task<IActionResult>  Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request."); 

    var isAuthenticated = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated; 
    var idName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.Identity.Name) ? "null" : principal.Identity.Name;
    log.LogInformation($"principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated = '{isAuthenticated}' and principal.Identity.Name = '{idName}'");
    var owner = (principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))?.Value;
    
    return new OkObjectResult($"principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated = '{isAuthenticated}' and principal.Identity.Name = '{idName}'");
    
}

private static string GetIdentityString(ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
    var userIdClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    if (userIdClaim != null)
    {
        // user identity
        var userNameClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
        return $"Identity: ({identity.AuthenticationType}, {userNameClaim?.Value}, {userIdClaim?.Value})";
    }
    else
    {
        // key based identity
        var authLevelClaim = identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/authlevel");
        var keyIdClaim = identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid");
        return $"Identity: ({identity.AuthenticationType}, {authLevelClaim?.Value}, {keyIdClaim?.Value})";
    }
}
```

Comment: It did the changes as proposed. However, I do get the same information. It does not seem to be the same sid I am getting on the mobile app but some other id...

Comment: With what was discussed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Understanding-User-Ids) regarding stable_sid vs sid, I am not what has changed over time.